# Angular, watching for added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a list

```
<ul>
    <li my-directive></li>
    <li my-directive></li>
    <li my-directive></li>
    <li my-directive class="selected"></li>
    <li my-directive></li>
    <li my-directive></li>
</ul>
```

And I'm adding classes to li and need to keep track of the data from the li which has that certain class. Should I place the directive on the ul and li?

I tried both approaches.

appControllers.directive('myDirective', function () {

```
function link  (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('.sc-selected', function(){
        if(element.hasClass('.sc-selected')) {
            console.log('has class');
        }
    });

}
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        value: "@"
    },
    link: link
}
scope.$apply();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: apart from syntax problems , the concept is wrong, you need to watch the data model(s) that cause the classes to change. You can't throw a class name into a watch either. Could watch the class attribute but that is just not the angular way

Comment: multiple things. well your HTML says class='selected', but your has class function looks for '.sc-selected'. The other thing is you are trying to $watch on '.sc-selected' when only scope variables can be watched

Comment: How is the selected class assigned in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you use $observe to watch for changes in attributes (info on this page):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes